# htaccess to serve from subfolder but not getting directly to it

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm serving contents from one dir as if it were other dir, like this:

```
mysite.com/dir/etc ==> mysite.com/realdir/dir/etc
```

To achieve this my rules in my htaccess file are:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/([^\/]+)[\/]?(.*)$
RewriteCond realdir\/%1 -d
RewriteRule ^ realdir/%1/%2 [L]
```

But this also allows to visit the real path directly. I don't want my users to be able to visit the real path, I want just one path to access the content. I've tried with redirects but I'm causing infinite loops.

Please help. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
# No acces to realdir, redirect to root with same path
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+realdir/(.*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

# rewrite mysite.com/dir/etc ==> mysite.com/realdir/dir/etc
RewriteCond realdir/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)[/]?(.*)$ realdir/$1/$2 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks @Croises for your help but it did not work in my case. It help me anyway. Possibly my question was not well written.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me...

```
# redirecting when trying to access real location
# and avoiding loops checking the redirect status
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/realdir(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# serve realdir if realdir/subdir exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/([^\/]+)(.*)$
RewriteCond realdir/%1 -d
RewriteRule ^ realdir\/%1%2 [L]
```